# how to slice between two elements in a pandas series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Series containing a column with names and their nationalities in parenthesis.
I want this column to contain just the individuals nationality and without parenthesis, with the same index.

```
0             LOMBARDI Domingo (URU)
1                  MACIAS Jose (ARG)
2                TEJADA Anibal (URU)
3              WARNKEN Alberto (CHI)
4                REGO Gilberto (BRA)
5              CRISTOPHE Henry (BEL)
6           MATEUCCI Francisco (URU)
7                  MACIAS Jose (ARG)
8                LANGENUS Jean (BEL)
9                TEJADA Anibal (URU)
10              SAUCEDO Ulises (BOL)
```

I have tried using .split(' ')[2] to the series.

But found out "'Series' object has no attribute 'split'."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [str](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html) accessor on series.

```
df.name.str.split('(').str[1].str[:-1]
```

Output:

```
0     URU
1     ARG
2     URU
3     CHI
4     BRA
5     BEL
6     URU
7     ARG
8     BEL
9     URU
10    BOL
Name: name, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `extract`

```
s.str.extract('.*\((.*)\).*',expand=True)[0]
Out[463]: 
0    URU
1    ARG
2    URU
3    CHI
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `slice`. May not be optimal as it assumes the right side of the string is constant but it's another possible solution.

```
df.name.str.slice(start = -4).str[:-1]
```